# Sealing water leak between kitchen cabinets and floor

Tags: flooring, kitchens, waterproofing, ceramic-tile, sealant

Since moving into our house 5 years ago, we have spilled a large amount of water on our kitchen floor a few times. When this happens, the water leaks into the floor boards and drips all the way into our basement.

Based on where the dripping is occurring, it seems that the source of the leak is where the ceramic tiles meet the cabinets in one corner of the kitchen. There is not an incredibly noticeable gap here, but it does look like it may not be sealed properly.

Other than not spilling water, what is the best way to fix this?

Is it typical to seal around the edges of the cabinet with caulk or some other sealant?

Any specific recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably run a bead of caulk or silicone around the edges of the floor. Many tile grout manufacturers also make matching caulk, but you'd likely have to know the manufacturer and color to match it perfectly. It's unclear that this would actually prevent the water from dripping into the basement though as there are likely numerous cracks, gaps, and alternative paths that it could take.

Answer (score 1):

It is not typical to turn your kitchen (or bathroom, or any room) into a bathtub. While you could attempt to seal against the baseboards as a temporary containment measure, water still finds a way and every time things get wet they'll degrade further. Finishes will blister. Wood will swell and then split or crumble. Mold and stains will develop. This is why commercial kitchens are all tile and stainless steel.

Deal with the spill issue instead.